# AWK multiple patterns substitution

Tags: awk

Using AWK I'd like to process this text:

```
#replace count 12
in in
  #replace in 77
main()
{printf("%d",count+in);
}
```

Into:

```
in in
ma77()
{pr77tf("%d",12+77);
}
```

When a '#replace' declaration occurs, only the code below it is affected. I've got:

```
/#replace/ { co=$2; czym=$3 }
!/#replace/ { gsub(co,czym); print }
```

However I'm getting only

```
in in
ma77()
{pr77tf("%d",count+77);
}
```

in return. As you can see only the second gsub works. Is there a simple way to remeber all the substitutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use an array to store the substitutions:

```
$ awk '/#replace/{a[$2]=$3;next}{for(k in a)gsub(k,a[k])}1' file
in in
ma77()
{pr77tf("%d",12+77);
}
```